# Python - fast filter large list/dict of objects by attribute values

Tags: python, search, filter, indexing

I have a large dictionary of orders with keys equal to order ids:

```
class Order():

    def __init__(self, ord_id, price, status='open'):
        self.ord_id = ord_id
        self.price = price
        self.status = status


orders = {'1': <order1>, '2': <order2>, ... , 'N': <orderN>}
```

How to find the orders with price less or equal to the given value? The filtering occurs thousands times per second. Dict/list comprehensions are too slow in this case.

A custom index or some b-tree library or database is probably required to avoid full loops, but I would like to keep it as simple as possible.

The orders that satisfy filter conditions are usually 1% of total.

Answer (score 0):

Python's generators are usually fast:

```
def filterbyprice(seq, max_price):
   for el in seq:
       if seq[el].price <= max_price: yield el
```

Generators do not return lists, but an element at a time, so they do not consume memory.

If you call that function in a loop, this will be faster than creating a list and looping over that list:

```
#this is the generator ("yeld" makes the function a generator)
def filterbyprice(seq, max_price):
   for el in seq:
        if seq[el].price <= max_price: yield el

class Order():
    def __init__(self, ord_id, price, status='open'):
        self.ord_id = ord_id
        self.price = price
        self.status = status

orders = {'1':Order(1,12),'2':Order(1,9),'3':Order(1,1)}

for cheap_order in filterbyprice(orders, 10):
    print cheap_order, orders[cheap_order], orders[cheap_order].price
```

output:

```
3 <__main__.Order instance at 0x00B90170> 1
2 <__main__.Order instance at 0x00B90148> 9
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not much faster then list(dict) comp, as in this case the full loop over all the orders is required as well. What would help is some kind of custom data structure in which it's not necessary to loop over all the orders. The orders that satisfy the filter conditions are usually 1% of total.

Comment: Maybe you can sort your `orders` dictionary by price ascending, that way you can stop the filter loop when the first price is higher than the given value. - With this you have to loop over the dict when insering some new order but you'll save time in searching cheap orders.

Comment: Although it's a good idea, I can't use it, because the orders are actually more complicated and have more attributes to filter by than in this question's example.

Comment: Uhm... making a list of orders id, sorted by price? but this is a complication and don't fulfil your "simple is better" request.

Comment: "Simple" means it's better not to use a database.

Comment: So you can make a second "twin" list/dict of ordered orders, containg just ids. You can order this second list by price ascending, filter this lits to find the ones with price lower than x, and from the id you foung getting data from the other dict.